# Kivy: Increasing space needed in BoxLayout?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have a lot jammed in the top left corner of my current GUI that I'm trying to basically spread out and have my image be a normal size (similar to the mock up shown below). I guess I need to expand the Y direction downward to fit it at (making the top region larger to fit it all)? However, when I change `size_hint_y` to > 1 it spaces the text upward and it cuts off outside of the GUI. Any ideas? Thanks very much!

Current Layout: 
[image]

My goal: 
[image]

My kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
<WeatherWidget>:
    cols: 1
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_x: 1
            size_hint_y: 1
            orientation: "vertical"
            Image: 
                source: 'Code32.png' 
                keep_ratio: False
                halign: 'center'
            Label:
                text: root.current_temperature()[:3] 
                bold: True
                font_size: 40
            Label:
                text: root.high_low_temp(0)
                font_size: 15
                color: [1,255,1,1]
            Label:
                text: root.get_location()
                font_size: 15
                color: [1,1,1,1]
                bold: True
            Label:
                text: root.sunrise()
                font_size: 10
                color: [1,1,1,1]
            Label:
                text: root.sunset()
                font_size: 10
                color: [1,1,1,1]
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Image: 
                source: 'Code32.png'
            Label: 
                text: root.forecast_day(1)
            Label: 
                text: root.high_low_temp(1)
                font_size: 12
                color: [1,255,1,1]
        Label:
            text: root.forecast_day(2)
        Label:
            text: root.forecast_day(3)
        Label:
            text: root.forecast_day(4)
        Label:
            text: root.forecast_day(5)
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                Button:
                    text: root.TimeHours + ':' + root.TimeMinutes
                    size_hint_x: 1
                    font_size: 40
                    size: self.size
                    bold: True
                    halign: 'center'
                Label:
                    text: root.current_date()
                    size_hint_x: 1
                    font_size: 15
                    bold: True
                    halign: 'center'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is as follow:

### 1. Divide Window into 2 Sections

Set the top section to 30% (0.3) of the parent's height by using size_hint_y = 0.3. The bottom section to 70% (0.7) of the parent's height using size_hint_y = 0.7

### 2. Avoid Top Left Corner Jam Up

To spread out the widgets in the top left corner, use size_hint_y = 1

### Snippet

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint_y: 0.3
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: 1
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            Image:
```

### dailyview.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
<WeatherWidget>:
    cols: 1
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint_y: 0.3
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: 1
            orientation: "horizontal"
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                Image:
                    source: 'Weather/partly_cloudy_night@2x.png'
                    keep_ratio: False
                    halign: 'center'
                Label:
                    text: root.current_temperature()[:3]
                    bold: True
                    font_size: 40
                Label:
                    text: root.low_high_temp(0)
                    font_size: 15
                    color: [1,255,1,1]
                Label:
                    text: root.get_location()
                    font_size: 15
                    color: [1,1,1,1]
                    bold: True
                Label:
                    text: root.sunrise()
                    font_size: 10
                    color: [1,1,1,1]
                Label:
                    text: root.sunset()
                    font_size: 10
                    color: [1,1,1,1]
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                Image:
                    source: 'Weather/partly_cloudy_day@2x.png'
                Label:
                    text: root.forecast_day(1)
                Label:
                    text: root.low_high_temp(1)
                    font_size: 12
                    color: [1,255,1,1]
            Label:
                text: root.forecast_day(2)
            Label:
                text: root.forecast_day(3)
            Label:
                text: root.forecast_day(4)
            Label:
                text: root.forecast_day(5)
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_y: None
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    Button:
                        text: root.TimeHours + ':' + root.TimeMinutes
                        size_hint_x: 1
                        font_size: 40
                        size: self.size
                        bold: True
                        halign: 'center'
                    Label:
                        text: root.current_date()
                        size_hint_x: 1
                        font_size: 15
                        bold: True
                        halign: 'center'
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: 0.8

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: 0.7
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                size_hint_y: 1
                text: "News Sections"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            Button:
                size_hint_y: 0.5
                text: "Stock Quotes"
            Button:
                size_hint_y: 0.5
                text: "Live Sports Scores"
```

## Output

[image: Figure 1 - Buttons for News, Stock Quotes, and Live Sports Scores]
[image: Figure 2 - Using RecycleView]

Comment: I think he must also set the size_hint_y of each widget in the first boxlayout

Comment: Thanks all for the answer. As a side note, is it possible to make a label (eg. news sections) as a scrollable label and nothing else? From what I could find online it looked like you have to inherit it where I have GridLayout, so wasn't sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to make a label as a scrollable. My recommendation is to use RecycleView. Please check out the Kivy RecycleView documentation at https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html